# Drupal Data module to feed external postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-views

I wanna take profit of Drupal 7 and its Views to create a form that should feed also an external PostgreSQL database.

I discovered the Data module, which lets you create the desired tables and set up foreign keys, primary keys and so on.

Lets say I create all the tables and its relationships via Data module. Also the form to feed the data via Views.

When user adds new data via the form in Drupal, there is an easy way to add this new data to an external database? I absolutely need this synchronization (the external database must be presented 'clean', no Drupal stuff, to an external institution)

Moreover, it would be possible to add extra CONSTRAINTS to Drupal tables as I can do in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

There is supposed to be a way for Drupal to connect to a different database but I haven't been successful to do it. If I were doing this, I would create a custom module that executes a script when the form is submitted. This script could then use "old-fashion" php to insert the data to the external database.

[Here are some information on how you create a Hello World module](https://drupal.org/node/778734)

In you module file you should then create a function that goes something like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  if ($form['id'] == 'the-id-of-the-submitted-form')
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_myfunction';
}

function mymodule_myfunction($form){
  // Here you put your code
  // The form values should be in the array $form['values']
}
```